# Angular: Can't update property in class when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, angular

In my class I have a property called "curSelectedSite" which is set to null by default:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  curSelectedSite = null;

  displayFn(site): string {
    this.curSelectedSite = site;
    return site ? site.name : site;
  }

  addSite(): void {
      console.warn(this.curSelectedSite) // outputs "null" and not the chosen autocomplete value as it should
  }
}
```

In my markup I have a autocomplete field which lets the user choose a site from a list of sites:

```
<mat-form-field class="field">
    <md-input-container>
        <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" placeholder="Choose Site" id="choose-site">
    </md-input-container>
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let site of sites" [value]="site">
            {{site.name}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>

<button mat-raised-button (click)="addSite()">Add Site</button>
```

The `displayFn` method fires when the user selects an option from the dropdown. As you can see I'm updating the `curSelectedSite` property when that happens with what the user chose. However when "Add Site" button is clicked **AFTER** a user chooses something it outputs `null` which is the original value and not the updated one. Why?

Comment: What happens when you log site inside of displayFn? It doesn't seem like you are passing anything to that function.

Comment: Outside the scope of `displayFn(site)`, the value of `curSelectedSite` is null

Comment: Also, if the purpose of displayFn is to set `curSelectedSite`, why do you return anything?

Comment: The reason why `curSelectedSite` is not updating is because `displayFn` is a function that is passed as an input parameter of `map-autocomplete`. the autocomplete uses that function to transform the display value. The scope of `displayFn` is the autocomplete component, not your component. So really you are updating `curSelectedSite` of the autocomplete component

Comment: @LLai makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At very minimum you'd need to bind the value of the autocomplete `<input>` to class property `curSelectedSite`. Without this binding, Angular has no way of knowing to update the value of `curSelectedSite` when the user selects an option from the autocomplete dropdown/menu.

This can be with [NgModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) or a form structure such as [Template Drive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms) or [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).

```
<mat-form-field class="field">
    <md-input-container>
        <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" placeholder="Choose Site" id="choose-site" [(ngModel)]="curSelectedSite">
    </md-input-container>
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let site of sites" [value]="site">
            {{site.name}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>

<button mat-raised-button (click)="addSite()">Add Site</button>

{{curSelectedSite}}
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/gjjmjdeexdne) in action.

Hopefully that helps!